# why int array go out of bound and print junk values but char array not?

Tags: arrays, pointers

I am looping through an int and char array , using element id(var) and pointer, in int array its giving OOB junk values but for char array its printing the correct values, even I don't use '\0', why?
below is code for char array :

```
char name[7] = {'R','a','s','h','m','I','\0'};
    int i=0;
    while(name[i])
    {
        printf("value of a = %c \n",name[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

below for int array :

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int *p,i=0;     
p=a;    

while(a[i])
{
    printf("value of a = %d \n",a[i]);
    i++;
}


while(*p)
{
    printf("value of p = %d \n",*p);
    p++;
}

Below is the O/P of int array : 
    value of a = 1
    value of a = 2
    value of a = 3
    value of a = 4
    value of a = 5
    value of a = 5
    value of a = 6487552
    value of p = 1
    value of p = 2
    value of p = 3
    value of p = 4
    value of p = 5
    value of p = 7
    value of p = 6487576
    
    Below is the O/P of char array : 
    
    value of a = R
    value of a = a
    value of a = s
    value of a = h
    value of a = m
    value of a = i
```

Comment: Do you understand what the condition in the while loop is doing? If so, the answer is self explanatory. If not, you should go back to the tutorial for a bit.

Comment: When you _declare_ `char name[7]` it allocates 7 bytes, and if you only give 6 bytes in the initializer -- `{'R','a','s','h','m','I'}` -- the remaining byte(s) is(are) filled with `'\0'`. Similarly a partially initialized array of numbers is 'extended' with number `0` or `0.0` as applicable, of pointers with `NULL`, etc. If you do `int a[6]={1,2,3,4,5}` you will also get a 'sentinel' zero, and no garbage.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : in both loops (for int and char ), I am looping through till there is any value present in the array.. in both cases I am not checking for '\0', int loop going OOB, Char printing the available chars in array.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : If you see i have initialized the int array with 5 values,the size of array also 5, So no need of any extension. it should loop 5 times only, right ? but in result its giving 7 values , 2 extras i guess those are junks.

Comment: "_I don't use '\0',_" ... Except you do.  So your point is I clear.

Comment: In your third loop you are not printing the value of `p` as suggested in the text, but rather the value pointed to by `p` (i.e. `*p`).  Was that your intent? Or did you intend `printf("value of p = %p \n", (void*)p);`?

Comment: For `int a[5]` you have _allocated_ 5 and set 5 nonzero values, so there is no zero to terminate the loop and instead you are accessing garbage. (Technically this is Undefined Behavior and the C standard allows a 'skynet' implementation to start World War 3 and incinerate you, but in practice usually they just access garbage.) For `char name[7]` if you remove the `,'\0'` from the initializer, you have still _allocated_ 7 bytes and set only 6 of them, so there _is_ a zero even though you didn't write it, because zero of appropriate type (char/integer/pointer) is the 'residual' initializer.

Answer (score 0):

> ... even I don't use '\0' ..."

Except you do; you have that value at the end of the array `name`.

The condition `name[i]` in the while loop is implicitly cast to a Boolean result, and any integer type (such as `char`) with a value of zero (such as `'\0'`) will evaluate to `false`.

That is to say:

```
while(name[i])
```

is the same as:

```
while(name[i] != '\0' )
```

You have misunderstood the semantics of `while(name[i])`. It does not test whether a value exists, it simply tests whether the expression is true or false.  An array or memory location cannot have "no value" in C, and all non-zero values are implicitly `true`.

Your integer loop terminated only because it encountered a zero value in memory.  The behaviour is undefined, and in other cases may run indefinitely or generate a processor exception for example if you run into an invalid memory address.

To better observe what is happening here, change your test loops as follows:

```
do
{
    printf( "value of a = %02X \n", (unsigned)name[i] ) ;
    i++;
} while(name[i - 1]) ;
```

and:

```
do
{
    printf("value of a = %d \n",a[i]);
    i++;
} while(a[i - 1]) ;

do
{
    printf("value of p = %d \n",*p);
    p++;
} while(*(p - 1)) ;
```

or better yet, use your debugger to observe the memory directly.

If you wish to iterate only the length of an array, and the array has no sentinel value, then a correct method would be:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
for( int i = 0; 
     i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
     i++ )
{
    printf( "value of a = %d \n", a[i] ) ;
    i++;
}
```

Note here that the length of `a` here is determined automatically by the number of initialisers. You only need an explicit dimension if there will be fewer initialisers than the desired length.  Most often it is better to let the compiler determine the dimensions automatically where possible.

Comment: so the int loop giving the extra values because of undefined behavior.. it could be an infinite loop as well , but in my case it encountered 0 after printing 2 values so it stopped.in case of char , its checking for '\0' which is a 0(false/zero) value itself, What about a char array without a '\0' char ?, it is printing the values in loop correctly. Or it will also print an undefine values(infinite values) or if 0 encountered immediately it will print few values, or only what I am printing in the loop the char array?

Comment: char name[6] = {'R','a','s','h','m','I'};
    int i=0;
 while(name[i])
 {
  printf("value of a = %c \n",name[i]);
  i++;
 }
 this is the code i am talking about.

Comment: @RashmiShete but that is not the code in your question, so it is irrelevant. SO is not a discussion forum. If you have a new question, you need to post a new question. That said, it makes no difference whether the data type is `char` or `int`; they are simply different width integer types.  I have updated this answer with a suggested improvement to your test/inspection method that may help clarify.

Comment: ... also added  a correct way to iterate an array without a sentinel value.

Comment: So as per ur explanation, I understood that it does not matter what is the type of an array, if sentinel is not given , it will always be an undefined behavior. If i want to print the values for an array i have to explicitly provide a terminating value. another improved way to calculate the length you have provided in ur answer.